# In Telegraf how to include only specific values of a tag

Tags: regex, influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-plugins

I am using a prometheus plugin in Telegraf to get the data from promitor and push it to InfluxDB. However, as per my requirement there is one tag named as "resource_name" and it contains multiple values let's say ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]. Out of these values I only want ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"] and these only values should be inserted into InfluxDB.

To achieve my requirement I am using below plugin and using tagpass to allow only specific values.

```
[[inputs.prometheus]]
  metric_version = 2
  name_suffix = "_promitor_abcd"
  urls = ["http://IP:Port/metrics"]
  tagexclude = [ "host", "url" ]
  [inputs.prometheus.tagpass]
    resource_name = [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ]
```

After using this when I run this configuration file I am still able to see all the values in InfluxDB under "resource_name" tag or column and not the values which I specified above in my configuration file.

Can anybody help me to understand what went wrong here and how to push only specific values in influxDB?

Answer (score 0):

The `tagpass` parameter is one of the available [metric filters](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/CONFIGURATION.md#metric-filtering) in telegraf. `tagpass` is specific to the tag key and value. Metrics that contain keys and values specified by `tagpass` are emitted. So if you have a metric as follows:

```s
metric,color=red,height=3 value=2
metric,color=red,width=4 value=2
```

For exmaple the following tagpass config:

```
  [[outputs.influxdb.tagpass]]
    height = ["*"]
```

Would pass any metrics with the height tag. You can place any value you want to filter on, with globs supported as well.

Thanks!